# Make siunitx.el automatically recognize values and unit of unformatted text

Tags: latex, auctex, automation

I use `siunitx` to typeset units in LaTeX. This is quite painless when typesetting it directly because of Emacs's `siunitx.el` (see below).

However, sometimes I copy exercises or solutions containing units from the Web or other sources which are not formatted.

So I paste something like `50 m`, `50m/s`, `1.2 m` or `1,2 m` (german comma) into a file in Emacs. Now I want to be able to mark this, type `C-c C-m \SI` and make Emacs automatically recognize units and transform them to `\SI{50}{m}`, `\SI{50}{m\per s}`, `\SI{1,2}{m}` and so on.

Any ideas how to modify `siunitx.el` to achieve this?

```
;;; siunitx.el --- AUCTeX style file for Siunitx
(TeX-add-style-hook "siunitx"
              (function
               (lambda ()
             (TeX-add-symbols
              '("SI"       "Value" "Unit")
                      '("ang"      "Angle")
              ))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Something, perhaps a tad more automatic (but in general it's hard to get the representation right, you'd probably need to adjust that for your specific use-cases).

```
(defun try-replace-units (begin end)
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char begin)
    (while
        (re-search-forward
         "\\<\\([-+]?\\([0-9]+\\|[0-9]*[.,][0-9]+\\)\\(e[0-9]+\\)?\\)\\s-*\\([a-zA-Z/]+\\)" end)
      (replace-match
       (let ((num (replace-regexp-in-string
                   "\\." "," (match-string 1)))
             (unit (match-string 4)))
         (setf end (+ end 8))
         (format "\\SI{%s}{%s}"
                 num
                 (replace-regexp-in-string
                  "/" "\\per " (or unit "") nil t)))
       nil t))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of changing the existing `LaTeX-arg-siunitx-unit` function, which is designed for interactive use, I would define a new function to do this, to be inserted in your init file.  Here is a start of a solution

```
(defun mg-LaTeX-siunitx-SI-region (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (goto-char end)
  (insert TeX-grcl)
  (goto-char beg)
  (insert (concat TeX-esc "SI{"))
  (skip-chars-forward "[0-9\.,]")
  (insert (concat TeX-grcl TeX-grop)))
```

It can be improved to automatically remove space between value and unit.